# What did the legal advisor say in The Hitman?

Tags: translation, the-hitman

In the movie [*The Hitman*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102045/), Sal was enraged because he had been passed over for a plum assignment in favor of Grogan.

Sal loudly expressed his outrage to the crime boss, but at a crucial moment the legal advisor [interjects something in Italian](https://youtu.be/0zG-BiKm6KM?t=57s) (YouTube, NSFW language).

I've long wondered what she said; can anyone provide a translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She says "*hai visto e preso l'uomo migliore, non come questo stronzo*"

It means "**You met and hired the best man, not like this asshole**"

Please note that she's not mothertongue and her pronunciation isn't very clear (she pronunces "migliore" as "migliori" that's plural, actually).